# Find a polynomial with given characteristics

Tags: polynomials, interpolation

[image]

### Attempt

We can think of this as interpolating $(x_i, f(x_i))$ where $i=0,1,2$. Let $p(x)$ be the the polynomial we want. We can start by

$$ p(x) = f(x) + (x-x_0)A $$

taking derivative we obtain $p'(x) = f'(x) + A $ So, we can write now

$$ p(x) = f(x) + (x-x_0) (f'(x)-p'(x)) $$

Now notice that $p(x_1) = f(x_1)$ as desired. All we need now is to interpolate $x_2$. How can we do this? Is my approach correct so far ?

Comment: See [Birkhoff interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birkhoff_interpolation)

Comment: Why not to write $p(x)=a+b x+c x^2+d x^3$. Four parameters $(a,b,c,d)$ and four equations.